# Regex expression for IP address/CIDR in bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression, ip

I want to check if the user input is a valid IP address/CIDR in bash and I am using regular expressions to do that. So valid CIDR should be 0-32 and for IP from `(1-254).(1-255).(1-255).(1-255)/(1-32)` So my code currently is:

```
read -p "Input: " ip_address

if [[ $ip_address =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/[0-9]+$ ]];
    then
    echo "VALID"
else
    echo "NOT VALID"
fi
```

But it is too generous and accepts some not valid combinations. 
So a valid IP address/CIDR combination should be: `10.11.11.11/24` or `254.255.255.255/23` and invalid will be `256.19.11.11/24` because the first octet is higher than 255 or `222.222.222.222/33` here the CIDR is is higher than 32. 
Is there another way apart of regex to check for valid IP address/CIDR?

Comment: If you have the option to use Python, look at https://cyruslab.net/2018/04/10/pythonvalidate-an-ip-address/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To properly handle validation of an IP address or CIDR, use a library function specifically made for this, such as the `cidrvalidate()` Perl function in the `Net::CIDR` module:

```
$ perl -MNet::CIDR=cidrvalidate -e 'printf("%s\n", cidrvalidate($ARGV[0]) ? "valid" : "invalid")' -- 1.2.3.0/24
valid

$ perl -MNet::CIDR=cidrvalidate -e 'printf("%s\n", cidrvalidate($ARGV[0]) ? "valid" : "invalid")' -- 1.2.3.0/2
invalid

$ perl -MNet::CIDR=cidrvalidate -e 'printf("%s\n", cidrvalidate($ARGV[0]) ? "valid" : "invalid")' -- 1.2.3.0
valid
```

See `perldoc Net::CIDR` for what else this library can do.

The `--` are not necessary in the examples above but would be for arbitrary input from the user as otherwise, that input would be taken as an option by `perl` if it started with `-`.

The approaches below are variations on your attempt, which does not care about invalid netmasks.

---

A positive decimal integer between 0 and 255 may be matched by

```
[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]
```

A positive decimal integer between 0 and 32 may be matched by

```
[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[012]
```

Using this:

```
#!/bin/bash

n='([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'
m='([0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[012])'

IFS= read -rp 'Input: ' ipaddr

if [[ $ipaddr =~ ^$n(\.$n){3}/$m$ ]]; then
    printf '"%s" is a valid CIDR\n' "$ipaddr"
else
    printf '"%s" is not valid\n' "$ipaddr"
fi
```

The expression

```
^$n(\.$n){3}/$m$
```

would expand to the full regular expression for a valid CIDR spanning the complete length of the given string.

---

The other obvious way to do this is to read the *numbers* in the given string and test whether the first four are in the 0-255 range and whether the fifth is in the range 0-32:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='./' read -rp 'Input: ' a b c d e

for var in "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d" "$e"; do
    case $var in
        ""|*[!0123456789]*) 
            printf 'not a valid number: %s\n' "$var"
            exit 1
    esac
done

ipaddr="$a.$b.$c.$d/$e"

if [ "$a" -ge 0 ] && [ "$a" -le 255 ] &&
   [ "$b" -ge 0 ] && [ "$b" -le 255 ] &&
   [ "$c" -ge 0 ] && [ "$c" -le 255 ] &&
   [ "$d" -ge 0 ] && [ "$d" -le 255 ] &&
   [ "$e" -ge 0 ] && [ "$e" -le 32  ]
then
    printf '"%s" is a valid CIDR\n' "$ipaddr"
else
    printf '"%s" is not valid\n' "$ipaddr"
fi
```

Here we read five words into five variables. The inputted string is split into words on `.` and `/` when read (which means `3/3/3/3.2` would be parsed as valid, but see `$ipaddr` in the code).  Any non-integer data read would trigger the script to exit. We then start testing their values against the valid ranges. If any test fail, the address entered is not valid.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help Stephane Chazelas and @Kusalananda

Answer (score -1):

thats what i use:

```
#!/bin/bash
function checkCidrFormat {
  local ipCidr="${1}"
  local validIpCidr
  validIpCidr='(^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\/([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-2]))$'
  if [[ $ipCidr =~ ^$validIpCidr ]]; then
    echo "valid format"
    return 0
  else
    echo "not valid format"
    return 1
  fi
}

while true;
do
read -rp "ip cidr (eg. 172.16.16.32/27): " cidr
if checkCidrFormat "${cidr}"; then
  echo "do something"
fi
done
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I am pretty new to scripting and this was something i dont understood until now. Added shebang.

Comment: Nice :-) The shebang tells the system which shell to use for running the script. For example Debian's default shell is dash, so `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/usr/bin/sh` would cause the script to fail as it's not fully POSIX-compliant. These are just symlinks to fully POSIX-compliant `dash`. Don't know which Linux you run, but at least in Debian installing `debscripts` brings `checkbashisms` which can be used to, well, check for bashisms (i.e. non-POSIX bash-specific expressions / options / etc.) in a script.